# goodness of fit vs independence test in finite population case

Tags: chi-squared-test, survey, contingency-tables

I have a finite population frame. Around 80% of the frame members have e-mail addresses, and a survey was sent via e-mail to those people. Roughly 20% of those to whom e-mails were sent replied to the survey.

Ignoring non-response for the moment, we want to know if the population with e-mails is typical of the general population, using information from the population frame. For example, for everyone in the frame, we know their environment (i.e. are they navy, army or air force).

My colleague tested this issue by doing a contigency test of e-mail vs environment, and got a significant result. p-value=0.007.

I did a one-way goodness of fit test -- comparing the distribution of air, sea and land people in the e-mail population to the true proportions of same in the overall population. I did this on the grounds that we are in a finite population context, so the population proportions can be viewed as ground truth. p-value=0.334

I also computed effect sizes for each analysis: 0.036 vs 0.018 respectively.

(Note, I did not consider a Rao-Scott adjustment, since the R-S tends to fall apart, in my experience, when the sampling fraction is large ... which it is in this case.)

I am considering a third option, which is to draw random samples of 80% from the population, compute the effect sizes of the one-way tests, and then see where the actual e-mail population compares to the bunch.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the actual question was cut off?

Comment: You're right. Thanks. But there wasn't much more to it, as you can see.